# Is it possible to route *.example.com to a single machine without registering extra domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, domain

I would like to achieve something similar to what wordpress.com does - giving each user its own subdomain. user1.wordpress.com would in the VirtualHosts setup of Apache would have its DocRoot at /user/user1, for instance.

Now, our hosting service provider takes a fee for creating a domain, and in our case this would mean a ridiculous number of domains with a matching price. After some googling on DNS I came over a description of a [DNAME record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNAME_record#DNAME_record). That seems to fit the bill precisely. Any reason why my service provider would not do this, or why I should not do this?

Comment: If your hosting provider charges a fee for creating a subdomain (e.g. user1.mydomain.tld, the new domain being the user1 part), then switch hosting provider. It's almost a steal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my personal opinion, you need to switch hosting providers. If I understood you correctly, they are charging for *subdomains* which are otherwise *completely free* to create and use.

Anyway, no, there should be no additional cost for inserting this entry (other than the one they appear to charge). They only reason they wouldn't do this is so they can profit from the fact you cannot be bothered to get a better deal elsewhere. I do not know of a server setup that wouldn't support this very simple feature (that is, Apache and Bind support it out of the box).

#### How to do it:

A `*.example.com` record need not be a DNAME record specifically. What you essentially want is just a normal A record that points `*.example.com` to `1.2.3.4` (where the IP represents the shared IP the website is hosted on. If you're not sure what it is, just look at your `example.com  IN A` record - it has to resolve to it):

```
*.example.com   IN   A  1.2.3.4
```

and then Apache will take it from there, just setup the `VirtualHost` to have the correct entry (I think it's `ServerName`) to be `*.example.com` and everything will match correctly (i.e. it'll load the correct `DocumentRoot`).

Just so you know: you cannot circumvent the fact that Apache will need to be (manually) configured. Some hosting providers may not do this, and if they don't, **leave**!

Comment: Then what is the difference between an A record and a DNAME record? From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNAME_record#DNAME_record I get the impression that there is 1:1 correspondance between an ip and a hostname, whereas a DNAME is like a CNAME, except that it can point to include multiple subdomains (such as *.bar.com).

Comment: The effect of them, in this case, would be the same. However, you should be aware that when a lookup is made for `hello.example.com`, it will `DNAME` to `example.com` - but this is still not an IP address. A futher DNS lookup will be made (analogous to resolving a `CNAME`) to convert `example.com` into its IP via the A record. This extra step is good if you only want to update a single record when you change IPs, but I think overall the overhead is not worth it if you only have 2 records (`*.example.com.` and `example.com.`).

Comment: Aha, actually, I missed the point where DNAME refers to _hostnames_, whereas A records refers to ips. Thanks!